# Почему в режиме debug данные приходят полностью, а в обычном режиме - теряются? Swift

Tags: ios, json, сокет, swift

Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой. Приложение при запуске/нажатии на кнопку обновить запрашивает у сервера данные. Он их присылает в `JSON`. Когда количество присылаемых объектов стало 5-6 штук, то началась ерунда: если я запускаю приложение без  breakpoint`ов, то данные приходят не полностью (смотрите на скрин - это то, что пришло.) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я поставлю breakpoint в моменте, где происходит прием данных и запущу приложение. То данные придут целиком! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это взрывает мозг! Почему такое происходит? Я не могу отследить это в дебаг-режиме, потому что в нем данные всегда приходят в целости. Передача данных происходит через сокеты. Использую библиотеку `SwiftSocket`
Прикрепляю код, где происходит прием данных:

```
func SendRequest(request: String) -> String {
    var response = ""
    var (success, errmsg) = client.connect(timeout: 1)
    if success {
        var (success, errmsg) = client.send(str: request + "\n" )
        if success {
            while(true) {
                var data = client.read(8192*10)
                if (data == nil) {
                    break
                }
                if let d = data {
                    if let str = String(bytes: d, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        print(str)
                        response += str
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            print(errmsg)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print(errmsg)
    }
    return response
}
```

Вот этот init
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не такая уж редкая проблема - когда срабатывает брейкпоинт, это дает приложению несколько секунд чтобы обработать какие то моменты подвязанные на время. пробуйте дебажить nslog'ами вместо брейкпоинтов. и тоже надо помнить, что слишком много nslog'ов могут создать такую же ситуацию, где работа приложения замедлится и какие то race conditions пропадут

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Попробовал покрутить - и вот что выяснилось. Вся проблема в этой строчке `if let str = String(bytes: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        {
                            print(str)
                            response += str
                        }` swift почему-то ни в какую не заходит в блок if, хотя data полностью забит байтами. Почему не удается преобразование в string?

Comment: выведите в консоль что у вас в str, и data.length тоже

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko в строке лежит `nil` а  data.length = 1024. Не проходит преобразование это  `String(bytes: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)`  data это у меня `[UInt8]`

Comment: попробуйте NSUTF16StringEncoding, может поможет

Comment: если нет, может быть поможет поменять на init(bytes:length:encoding:)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko мистика, но `str` все равно остается = `nil`

Comment: Из предположений: большой буфер `read(8192*10)` - попробуйте уменьшить (к примеру, до 1024) и проверить.

Comment: предположу что что то с кодировкой. Я бы попробовал все по списку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так (Swift 3)

```
let str = d.withUnsafeBufferPointer { buf in
    return String(validatingUTF8: buf.baseAddress!)
}
```

правда не факт что пытаясь конвертировать в строку чанки (куски) передаваемых данных Вы пройдете валидацию UTF8. Может обрывы связанны именно с этим.
Имеет смысл сначала принять весь поток данных, а уже потом конвертировать его в строку. Вот пример поясняющий возможную причину обрыва

```
let validUTF8: [CChar] = [67, 97, 102, -61, -87, 0]
 validUTF8.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
     let s = String(validatingUTF8: ptr.baseAddress!)
     print(s)
 }
 // Prints Optional("Café")

 let invalidUTF8: [CChar] = [67, 97, 102, -61, 0]
 invalidUTF8.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
     let s = String(validatingUTF8: ptr.baseAddress!)
     print(s)
 }
 // Prints nil
```